# How to prevent rotting of Holy Basil when propagating with water?

Tags: houseplants, shrubs, herbs, basil

So I'm propagating Holy Basil from cuttings. I take a nodal area cut and prune the leaves except for the top ones and dip them in water for about a week or two. The top leaves do not touch the water. From what I've noticed, the water gets sucked up to the top leaves and they always stay wet. I think that is normal. But however, I've noticed that the leaves develop an infection, turn black in color and rot away. The stem stays healthy though. And I promptly change the water every 2 days.

Is there a way I can prevent this rotting? Or even if there is a different and a foolproof way to propagate Basil by cuttings, I would much appreciate it.

Thanks!